# Rotational vector fields

Tags: vectors

If curl of a vector field is zero, then it is irrotational. The only such vector field is a conservative field.  I want to know why rotational vector fields are not conservative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Conservative means that the field ${\bf A}$ satisfies

$$
\int_{a:~path~1}^b {\bf A }\cdot d{\bf x} = \int_{a:~path~2}^b {\bf A }\cdot d{\bf x}
$$
this is to say that the result of the integral does not depend on the path chosen to join points $a$ and $b$. In particular this implies that

$$
\oint_{any~loop} {\bf A} \cdot d{\bf x} =0
$$
But a rotational field has $\nabla \times {\bf A} \neq 0 $ and Stokes' theorem tells us that for a rotational field:

$$
\oint_{loop} {\bf A}\cdot d{\bf x} = \int_{area~inside~loop} \nabla \times {\bf A} \cdot d{\bf S}
$$
Which will not be zero anymore.

Comment: $\nabla \times {\bf A}$ won't be zero but the integral can still be zero as various sub-areas can cancel each out.

Comment: Indeed, it could be zero by chance, but in general it will not be. In particular you can always choose a small enough loop around any given point such that the integral will not vanish.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to given a set of points to be included, to always find some cheapest area & contour for which it becomes 0 by chance.

Comment: That is a very interesting question!! Another somehow related question would be: Given ${\bf A}$ in the plane, construct a curve so that the circulation vanishes. I guess one approach would be trying to use a rectified approximation of the curve and then take the limit to get a smooth curve, if it exists at all. It is also clear that solving this problem would be a step towards answering your quesion. +1